# Telegram bot API: Can I mix a custom keyboard and a force_reply?

Tags: telegram-bot

I have a custom keyboard but to process the answer i need a force reply so i get the question back in the next message. I have done this:

```
var opts = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({ 
        keyboard: [['OK','Cancel']],
        one_time_keyboard: true,
        resize_keyboard: true,
        force_reply: true
    })
};
```

The keyboard works but not the force_reply. 
Force reply on its own works? Can i not use it in combination with a custom keyboard?

Comment: according to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841237/5320087
its not possible

Answer (score 7):

It may be late to help you, but here it goes.

Currently only one `reply_markup` field is allow and this field must contain only one of the following types: `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` or `ReplyKeyboardHide` or `ForceReply` (see [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage))

In any case, you can use `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` that will pop up a custom keyboard in the user app directly and code your bot so it only accept one of the answer in your own custom keyboards.

Furthermore, if you really want to force that the user reply, you can keep sending the same `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` after each user's **invalid** answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify your markup like this :

```
$replyMarkup = array(
  'force_reply' => true,
  'selective' => true
);
```

If you need to have `custom keyboard` you can follow this :

```
$keyboradsValue = array(
   array("button 1","button 2"),
   array("button 3","button 4"),
);
$replyMarkup = array(
  'keyboard' => $keyboradsValue,
  'force_reply' => true,
  'selective' => true
);
```

After that you need to encode your object using `json_encode`

```
$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup, true);
```

Finally you just put above code at your query string at the rest of `sendMessage`.

Comment: Did you actually try this?

Comment: If you want to do something you have to call a function. After clicking keyboard by user, That function should be called, After that, The result return to user by another keyboard or display something to user by the URL query which Telegram gave to you.