# Telegram inline keyboard and keyboard

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have question about Telegram bot.
I want keyboard and inline keyboard, Can I enable both of the features at the same time ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [Telegram documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup), **it's currently impossible** to pass two or more objects for `reply_markup` at the same time. `reply_markup` only accepts one of these objects at the same time:

1. [InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup)
2. [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup)
3. [ReplyKeyboardRemove](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove)
4. [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply)

And of course you cannot combine two or more objects together. If you wanna show keyboard and have inline keyboard too, you can show the keyboard in a message and after that send another message with inline keyboard.

Cheers,