# inline keyboard click doesnt call callback_query why?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

```
bot.onText(/(.+)$/, function (msg, match) {
    const opts = {
    reply_markup: {
      inline_keyboard: [
        [
          {
            text: 'Edit Text',
            callback_data: 'edit'
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, 'Original Text', opts);
});

bot.on("callback_query", function(callbackQuery) {
    // 'callbackQuery' is of type CallbackQuery
    console.log(callbackQuery);
});
```

I have looking for answer to this question, tried all the resources available on call_back. Such as
[Telegram bot inline keyboard via Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977699/telegram-bot-inline-keyboard-via-node-js)
[Telegram inline keyboard and keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750066/telegram-inline-keyboard-and-keyboard)
[How can create menu for telegram bot in bot father?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956166/how-can-create-menu-for-telegram-bot-in-bot-father/41967373#41967373)

Comment: Your code looks good, and works fine in my sandbox.

Comment: Hey @stdob-- is there any special step up? is the bot needs to be deployed to test the query?

Comment: Nothing special: provide token, and start...

Comment: Is it possible that you can provide me the complete setup how to do it? because I am not sure if i am going somewhere wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this like that?

```
bot.on('callback_query', function onCallbackQuery(callbackQuery) {
        const action = callbackQuery.data;
        const msg = callbackQuery.message;
        // do your stuff
        if (action === 'adress') {
        // do something if callback data is "adress", you can have multiple if statements for various cases
        }
});
```

That's how I got it working, hope it helps!

Comment: Nope it is not working. Is there any special setup needs to be done in BotFather?

Comment: @Smit Sad to hear that. I am most certain that absolutely no setup is required to be done in BotFather. Have you tried running the example from [this page in the docs?](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/examples/polling.js) And are you sure there is no issue with your polling / webHook setup? It might also be the case: as far as I know, this stuff is responsible for dealing with any feedback the bot receives.

Comment: @Smit Also in the comment section for the original question (where I can't comment for now, unfortunately) you asked if the bot needs to be deployed to a server. And the answer is no, it is not required. You can absolutely handle callback queries running the bot on your machine.